# Center navigation bar in WordPress avanta theme

Tags: html, css

I'm a WordPress newbie so please be gentle.

Using Avanta theme on WordPress version 4.3.1.

This is the site:
http://goo.gl/YoDI9a

Trying to center the top navigation menu bar.

Used the following custom CSS code but didn't make a difference:

```
.fusion-main-menu > ul {
  text-align: center !important;
  float: none !important;
}
.fusion-main-menu > ul > li > a, .fusion-main-menu > ul > li {
  float: none !important;
  text-align: center !important;
  display: inline-block !important;
}

.fusion-main-menu > ul ul {
  text-align: left !important;
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Your navigation bar already looks centered.

Comment: Although this is a WordPress site, it's not a WordPress issue. I've corrected the tags on your post to reflect that this is a CSS/HTML issue only.

Answer (score 0):

On line 5518 of http://www.acornoak.co.uk/wp-content/themes/Avada/style.css?ver=3.8.6.1 get rid of the "float: right;" line under the `.fusion-main-menu` selector.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is outside, in your `style.css` file change your `.fusion-main-menu` to this:

```
.fusion-main-menu {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 200;
}
```